# Why chmod does not save the permissions after a reboot?

Tags: linux, manjaro, chmod

When I run command `sudo chmod o+w /home` /home permissions change to:

`drwxr-xrwx   3 root root        4096 May 30 11:40 home`

When I reboot, it get back to:

`drwxr-xr-x   3 root root        4096 May 30 11:40 home`

I have verified where /home is mounted and on what type of filesystem with `df -T /home`:

```
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   49G   41G  6.1G  88% /
```

My question is: "Why the permissions do not last after a reboot?"
Thank you.

PS: I am using Manjaro.

Comment: There's a good chance something is running at boot time to make sure `/home` has sensible permissions.  The permissions you've set would enable anyone to, for example, rename anyone else's home directory.

Comment: The permissions should remain in the way that they are being set at boot. Why would you want users to be able to rename other users' home directories?

Comment: Tell us what your goal is. There is probably a better may.

Comment: @NasirRiley @AndyDalton  That's what I supposed. Do you have an idea on what would that be that's setting back the permission to original. 
@ctrl-alt-delor I wanted to enable write permissions for one user with using `chown`. This user will be accessing a file from the absolute path: /home/user123/Desktop/File1

Comment: Why are you giving _all_ users write access to `/home` when _some_ user needs something in `/home/user123/Desktop`?

Comment: Why not just put that file elsewhere and give the user access to it? That's a far better than giving all users write permissions to `/home`.